# Проект не загружается Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony

при загрузки страницы произошла ошибка .

> Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php5/sess_t1fjlqi1ffcvjhij8grjvnub92, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

как решить эту проблему ? Всем спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста посмотрите какие права, владелец и группа у /var/lib/php5/sess_t1fjlqi1ffcvjhij8grjvnub92. Из под какого пользователя загружен ваш Web-сервер? Какая операционная система используется? Если не сложно, добавьте эти уточнения в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте [этот раздел](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) руководства по установки Symfony. Возможно, указанные ниже команды решат вашу проблему.

Если операционная система MacOS:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/logs/* var/sessions/*

HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo chmod -R +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
sudo chmod -R +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" var
```

Если операционная система Linux:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Comment: Спасибо , но как то не получается включить ACLs

Comment: зачем давать права nginx, если работать будет php-fpm?

Comment: @Etki, спросите об этом у разработчиков Symfony :)

Comment: @MasterAlex да нет, я лучше у оставившего ответ спрошу.

Comment: @Etki,  я не собираюсь с вами спорить, когда я ставил Symfony по этому руководству, всё прошло как по маслу, а вы выбрали не тот ресурс для скандалов, не нравится ответ, напишите свой лучше